# Holder continuous derivative on bounded $D$ implies Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces

Suppose $D$ is a bounded, open, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose that $u \in C^{1,\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1]$, i.e. $u$ has a Holder continuous derivative with exponent $\alpha$. Is it true that $u$ is Lipschitz?

My thoughts are that $u \in C^{1,\alpha}$ implies $\nabla u$ is uniformly continuous, and hence bounded since $D$ is bounded.
Then $\nabla u$ bounded implies $u$ is Lipschitz. I don't know why but I feel like I may be forgetting some hypotheses. It doesn't feel quite right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It doesn't feel quite right.

And rightly so. Consider for example (identifying $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$) a slit annulus,

$$D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 1 < \lvert z\rvert < 2\} \setminus (1,2),$$

and $u(z) = \arg z$. Then the derivative of $u$ is Hölder-continuous, but $u$ is not Lipschitz continuous.

You can of course construct similar examples in higher dimensions.

What you need for the conclusion is that the distance of two points in $D$ doesn't differ by too much from the length of the shortest paths in $D$ between the points.

Comment: Where does my proof break though?

Comment: A bounded derivative only implies Lipschitz continuity if the distance of two points is not much shorter than some path between the two points. You have $$f(y) - f(x) = \int_0^1 \langle\nabla f(\gamma(t)),\gamma'(t)\rangle\,dt,$$ and you can only bound that by $\lVert\nabla f\rVert_\infty\cdot L(\gamma)$. So you need some constant with $L(\gamma)\leqslant C\cdot \lVert y-x\rVert$ for Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: Is there a name for sets with this property of $L(\gamma) \leq C ||y-x||$?

Comment: I think there is. I cannot remember it, unfortunately. Something like path-metric, I think.

Comment: For progeny, the term for when $L(\gamma) \leq C |y-x|$ is quasiconvex.